# Is it possible load ANDROID_HOME value in local.properties?

Tags: android, eclipse, ant, gradle, android-studio

I am writing an Android application using Android Studio + Gradle and, instead of writing the SDK pathname on local.properties as

```
sdk.dir=/opt/android/sdk
```

I would like to know if is possible write something like

```
sdk.dir=${ANDROID_HOME}
```

so I could push the local.properties to the Git repository without concerning myself with the SDK location.

Comment: I can't help but ask why you want to check that file into source - the point of it is to configure workspace/computer specific configuration, and is specifically intended not to be committed.

Comment: In order to allow run the build from bash with "gradle assembleRelase" command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gradle , and thus Android Studio, will automatically use `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable , no need to write it into local.properties (you can just delete this file).

please [see in gradle plugin user guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide), search for local.properties

Answer (score 1):

You should just remove that string from `local.properties`

That works for Eclipse ADT as well.